# TypeError: (0 , _react.useMemo) is not a function - react-native redux

Tags: react-native

*I have got this error and couldnt handle this.*

[image]

*Error is come up here. but I dont know why.*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class LibraryList extends Component {
    render() {
       return null;
    }
}

 const mapStateToProps = state => ({

        });

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LibraryList);
```

**EDİTED:**

*I solved this issue with these :*

[link1](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24543)

[link2](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/4757)

Answer (score 4):

I also came across this problem yesterday too, the issue is to do with the connect function react-redux, I tried an older version of redux and it worked.

Try, `npm install react-redux@6.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';

    class LibraryList extends Component {
        render() {
           return null;
        }
    }

   const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {

       }
            };

export default connect(mapStateToProps,null)(LibraryList);
```

Comment: Same error :(. I updated my react-native latest version as well but error is exists

Comment: kill npm server process and npm start and try again

Comment: u mean close panel and start again ?

Comment: open terminal and then go to path of project and run 'killall node -9' command then run 'npm start' command and reload your app.

Comment: I take this when run 'killall node -9' :   killall is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading `react-native`, `react` and cleaning xCode worked for me:

1. `$ yarn upgrade react-native@0.59`
2. `$ yarn upgrade react@16.8` .
3. `$ rm -rf node_modules`
4. And cmd + shift + k in xCode

[React documentation](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html)